# Увеличить эффективность рекурсии. Рюкзак

Tags: c#, алгоритм, рекурсия

Есть рекурсивный метод для решения задачи о рюкзаке 0/1:

```
public static void BestCostBackpack(List<Items> allitems, int maxweight)
        {
            if (allitems.Count > 0)
            {
                if (WeightCalculation(allitems) <= maxweight && CostCalculation(allitems) > bestcost) //WeightCalculation - подсчет веса всех предметов в List<Items> , CostCalculation - аналогично с ценностью вещей
                {
                    bestitems = allitems;
                    bestcost = CostCalculation(bestitems);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < allitems.Count; i++) //Перебор через рекурсию всевозможных вариантов рюкзака, варианты могут повторяться
            {
                List<Items> newitems = new List<Items>(allitems);
                newitems.RemoveAt(i);
                BestCostBackpack(newitems, maxweight);
            }
        }
```

Можно ли не меняя кардинально код убрать повторяющиеся варианты рюкзака?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Метод называется мемоизация.

Нужно завести структуру для хранения уже вычисленных подрешений - например, map с ключом (оставшийся вес; набор элементов) или что там у вас удобнее.

Если при входе в функцию обнаруживаете, что для таких параметров уже есть решение - возвращаете его, иначе считаете и записываете в map.